# ValueError: len(index) != len(labels) for groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use a simple groupby function in python but am running into problems. I have multiples of the same dates in python and am trying to take an average value. My data looks as such:

```
1    All dwellings  date
222        63810.0  1992
223        65183.0  1992
224        60818.0  1992
225        62397.0  1993
226        63218.0  1993
```

When I try and groupby I get this error:

```
uk_house.groupby(by='date', axis=1).mean()

ValueError: len(index) != len(labels)
```

I have looked this error up and it seems to occur when the dimensions are changing but surely this is the entire point of a groupby?

Could someone help me understand this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not add `axis=1`, when you pass the axis=1 , `pandas` will do column groupby not row

```
uk_house.groupby('date').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do an avg of the dweelings column , you may have to use the below code

```
uk_house.groupby(['date'])[['dweelings']].mean()
```